# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlDocument access head element

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

How do we access the head element in HtmlAgilityPack?

We have this code :

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
```

but when trying to get the head element

```
var head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head");
```

result is `head` is null

Comment: Does the html document have a `head` tag at all? How do you load your html into the `HtmlDocument`?

Comment: `doc.LoadHtml(page.OuterHtml);` where page is simple HTML, where does `doc` get its head element from?

Comment: @levi does the document you load (ie the page.OuterHtml) actually have a head tag?

Comment: @croxy I have added the head and its ok. but now I see that the string added to the body is being trimmed... any idea why?

Comment: How do you add the string to the body?

Comment: @croxy using the following `html += myHtmlString` - this is also how I add the head, etc... the string is not all that long

Comment: I cannot say much without seeing the full code. I would suggest opening a new question for this specific problem, because it is unrelated to the current question. Please add a description + your code to the new question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var head = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/html/head");
```